# List sub pages by custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the following to list all sub pages of the current page. I want to use wp_get_post_terms to filter these sub pages by custom taxomony term.

Current page

- taxonomy 1 title

- - sub page 1

- - sub page 2

- taxonomy 2 title

- - sub page 1

- - sub page 2

```
$mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );

foreach( $mypages as $page ) {      
    $content = $page->post_content;

    if ( ! $content ) 
        continue;       
    echo "<h2><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></h2>";
}
```

Can anyone help please?